# What is the Laurent expansion of $f(z)=\frac1{z-3}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series, laurent-series

What is the Laurent expansion of $f(z)=\dfrac1{z-3}$?

> In the region, $|z-3|>0$ ?

I just computed the Laurent expansion in the region $|z|>3$ by dividing the denominator by $\dfrac1z$ and making it as a geometric series.

I am not sure how to manipulate $f(z)$ so that this function can be somehow expressed as a laurent series in above region.

Answer (score 1):

The expression $f(z)=\frac1{z-3}$ is already the Laurent series around $|z-3|>0$.

Comment: Can I express this in terms of convergent series?

Comment: take $a_n=0$ for $n\ne -1$ and $a_{-1}=1$....